# node.js+express+socket.io with ipv6?

Tags: node.js, socket.io, ipv6

I have my code like below:

```
var gzippo = require('gzippo');

var app = require('express').createServer()
  , io = require('socket.io').listen(app);

io.enable('browser client gzip');
io.set('transports', [
    'websocket'
]);

app.use(gzippo.staticGzip(__dirname + '/'));

app.listen(8001);

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.sendfile(__dirname + '/main2.html');
});

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {...});
```

I use gzippo for gzip, express for http server, socket.io for websocket function.

The code beyond now work properly with requests from a ipv4 address.

So how to listen a request from my ipv6 address?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that socket.io fails to connect as it is unable to parse ipv6 url, cf https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io-client/issues/260

Comment: I tried my ipv6 address and it failed in my case, either. So this is a bug?

Comment: Would you be able to this test, unfortunately I do not have ipv6 routers - Code - 

`var net = require('net'); `
`var server = net.createServer();`
`server.listen(1600, '::1');`

and client side
`var socket = io.connect();`

Does this work?

Comment: I don't think it's possible. Since the client code is passed only when it is already connected in my original code, I have no way to pass `var socket = io.connect();` to client now.