# Socket.IO IPv6 (January 2013 Edition)

Tags: node.js, socket.io, ipv6

I need to use Socket.IO and its client to connect between two Node.js servers over an IPv6 network.

One year ago, this [didn't seem possible due to the address parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8550656/362536) with the client.  Now it seems that [at least one person has gotten it working](https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/issues/992).

So, I tried some simple test code on the server:

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(8124, '::1');
```

And, on the client:

```
io.connect('http://[::1]:8124');
```

This fails.  (No error is output, which I am investigating now.  I assume this is a bug in the crash handler I'm using from winston.)

I've also noticed that if I go to `http://[::1]:8124/` in Chrome, I don't get the usual, "Welcome to socket.io.", debugging message.  Strangely enough, if I go to `http://127.0.0.1:8124/`, I do get that message, despite telling the server to only listen on `::1`.

**As of version 0.9.11 of Socket.IO, is it possible to use IPv6?**  If so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(require('http').createServer().listen(8124, '::1'));
```

or (to get the debug message):

```
var server = require('http').createServer().on('request', function (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200);
    res.end('Welcome to socket.io.');
}).listen(8124, '::1');
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
```

I tested it with curl (`curl -g http://[::1]:8124/`) and nodejs:

```
require("http").get({hostname:"::1", port:8124,path:"/"}, function(res) {
    console.log("Got response: " + res.statusCode);
    res.on("data",function(chunk) {
        console.log("BODY: " + chunk);
    });
}).on("error", function(e) {
    console.log("Got error: " + e.message);
});
```

Using "real" hostnames works with the client:

```
require('socket.io-client').connect('http://ip6-localhost:8124/');
```

my /etc/hosts contains the entry `::1 ip6-localhost`, so if you have hostnames which point to IPv6 addresses only, this should work. (If the first connect didn't work it does not fallback to another address, so using localhost as name it didn't fallback to IPv6 from IPv4).

Sadly it looks like the nodejs url module (at least the version 0.6.19 in debian) doesn't support literal addresses, and therefore neither does the xmlhttprequest module:

```
console.log(require('url').parse('http://[::1]:8124/'));
```

The socket.io-client module doesn't support literal addresses either, but you could fool it like this:

```
require('socket.io-client').connect('http://blank:8124/', {host:'[::1]'});
```

This will use XMLHTTPRequest as backend though, so it still doesn't work with nodejs (perhaps it works with a "real" XMLHTTPRequest object in a browser, or a newer nodejs version).

**Update**: more recent node versions (tried v0.9.6-16-g9668df8) support literal ipv6 addresses in the url parser, and therefore in xmlhttprequest.

Comment: Thanks Stefan.  This seems to get the server going, but I am unable to connect to it from the client.  No error is being output... not sure why.  Are you able to connect to the server from the Node.js client?

Comment: @Brad hm, right - the clients looks more broken than the server. I updated the answer.

Comment: Is there a solution if you can't use a hostname (dns) and only the IPv6 address? The server side works as a charm, but client side I constantly run into the problem that the XMLHTTPRequest parses the IPv6 address wrong and that complains about cross-domain calls that aren't allowed.